# Custom UITableViewCell Remove Separation

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am appending a number of custom UITableViewCell into a UITableView, I have set the constraints so that there is no margin, however I cannot get rid of a small white line below it!

[image]

Does anyone know how I can achieve this using SWIFT, I have tried the objective-c code:

```
self.table.separatorType = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone
```

but I do not know how to convert into into Swift!

Comment: Try `self.table.separatorType = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.None` (note the .None)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by effectively setting the tableView's `separatorInset` to `UIEdgeInsetsZero`.

I'm not sure of the Swift equivalent of that, though.

EDIT: I just looked it up. It's pretty much the same in Swift:

```
tableView.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero
```